# EF Core In Memory database data leaking between unit tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit

I'm trying to mock my EF-Core database by using the in memory provider as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory.

I have structured my tests like so:

```
[Test]
public async Task PerformTest1() {
  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MeldingenModel>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(PerformTest1))
    .Options;
  var protos = new List<MeldingPrototype> { ... };
  var meldingen = new List<Melding> { ... };
  using (var seedingcontext = new MeldingenModel(options)) {

    seedingcontext.MeldingPrototypes.AddRange(protos);
    seedingcontext.Meldingen.AddRange(meldingen);
    seedingcontext.SaveChanges();
  }
  using (var db = new MeldingenModel(options))
  using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose(cgf => cgf.RegisterInstance(db))) {

    // do test
  }
}
```

The first section is to seed data into the database. Each test has a similar pattern, and each is using `nameof(<methodname>)` as argument to `UseInMemoryDatabase`. The way I understand the docstrings on that method, the different string arguments should ensure that all the created databased are separate, but they still seem to be affecting each other. If I run each test in isolation, they all pass, but running them all at once makes them fail. The reason for failure is that seed data from one method is also present during the other tests.

The test-framework I use is nUnit.

Can anyone help me get properly isolated testdatabases?

Comment: Hi @JAD, looks good at first glance. Do you have a sample app, or maybe a definition of you dbcontext at hand, so I can quickly set up a the same code, and check what's going on?

Comment: Oof, it's currently pretty big. Let me see if I can boil it down to a minimal working example.

Comment: from the sample tests you posted (and later removed) it looks like this in memory db data persists across running of the tests, I get conflicts on keys - but when i change key range everything works fine. I will find out more on what is the *lifetime* of this in memory db.

Comment: @ironstone13 I removed the sample tests, exactly because that was the reason my tests failed, and not in the actual version. In other words, it didn't reproduce what went wrong, sadly. I did however find the actual reason: Some of the entity objects that were not central to the test were reused between tests. The actual data was stored in their collections of foreign keys, and thus readded into the new databases.

Comment: I wonder what to do with this question. I could edit it so that it is answerable, and self-answer it. But makes the question a bit silly...

Comment: It's your call - If you think this might help someone in the future, then, by all means, post a proper answer. Otherwise you can remove / close the question. Do not leave in unanswered. This will cause many people reading it, with no benefit!

Answer (score 3):

I tend to do the following to make sure that I really have a separate database for each unit test.

```
public class MyTestClass
{
  [Test]
  public async Task PerformTest1()
  {
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MeldingenModel>()
      .UseInMemoryDatabase($"{ nameof(MyTestClass) }.{ nameof(PerformTest1) }")
      .Options;
  }
}
```

I see that you already have solved your issue. But still it is good practice to be sure, about the uniqueness of the database names.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: Also, make sure that none of the entities use you in your tests are shared between tests. It might seem obvious, but it was what bit me in the behind.